# unresolved linking error in a virtual function

Tags: c++

I'm getting an unresolved linking error for a couple of virtual functions. 
I have an interface `IFieldManager` and I implement it using `ImplFieldManager`.

So I have two functions that needs to be implemented `FieldToArea()` and `FieldToPoi()`. which are already implemented.

The full error message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall ImplFieldManager::FieldToArea(struct S3W::IField const &,struct S3W::IArea &)" (?FieldToArea@ImplFieldManager@@UAE_NABUIField@S3W@@AAUIArea@3@@Z)   Schiebel3DWorld (Libraries\Schiebel3DWorld\Schiebel3DWorld) D:\andre\OSGEarthLib_VS2015-build\Schiebel3DWorld\src\ImplIConnection.obj   1
```

My code :

```
#include "Schiebel3DWorld/include/IArea.h"
#include "Schiebel3DWorld/include/IField.h"
#include "Schiebel3DWorld/include/IPoi.h"
namespace S3W
{
    struct IFieldManager
    {
        IFieldManager() {}
        virtual ~IFieldManager() {}
        virtual bool FieldToArea(const IField& areas, IArea& manager) = 0;
        virtual bool FieldToPoi(const IField& areas, IPoi& manager) = 0;
    };
}


namespace S3W
{
struct IFieldManager;

struct IServerConnection : public CImplRefPtr, virtual public IRefPtr
{  


   virtual IFieldManager* GetFieldManager() = 0;
};

}

namespace S3W
{

struct ImplConnection : public S3W::IServerConnection, public SNet::SThread

{
    // Inherited via IServerConnection
    virtual S3W::IFieldManager * GetFieldManager() override;

};

}


#include "Schiebel3DWorld/include/IFieldManager.h"

struct ImplFieldManager : public S3W::IFieldManager
{
    ImplFieldManager(){}
    ~ImplFieldManager() {}

    // Inherited via IFieldManager
    virtual bool FieldToArea(const S3W::IField & areas, S3W::IArea & manager) override;
    virtual bool FieldToPoi(const  S3W::IField & areas, S3W::IPoi & manager) override;
};


S3W::IFieldManager * S3W::ImplConnection::GetFieldManager()
{
    return new ImplFieldManager();
}



#include "ImplFieldManager.h"


bool ImplFieldManager::FieldToArea(const  S3W::IField & areas, S3W::IArea & manager)
{
    return false;
}

bool ImplFieldManager::FieldToPoi(const  S3W::IField & areas, S3W::IPoi & manager)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: First of all, please edit your question to include the actual error messages. In full, complete and with any possible information notes, and without any editing. Then can you tell us *where* `FieldToArea` and `FieldToPoi` are defined? All we see is their *declaration*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have edited my question. Hope I got an answer :)

Comment: And `ImplFieldManager ` is not in the `S3W` namespace? Or another namespace you're missing? And you actually build with the source file where the functions are defined (or the corresponding object file)?

Comment: ImplFieldManager is not in the S3W namespace, yes I build with the source file where the functions are defined